# java.lang.NullPointerException in my (very basic) code

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am new to programming and am teaching myself with an online tutorial. I'm pretty useless just now and have had LOADS of compiling errors. However, now my programme compiles, but I get a null pointer exception and I just can't work out why. I think I've declared all the variable so I'm not sure what I've referenced incorrectly.

Here's my code (apologies again for it being so basic):

```
public class CalorieCount {

    public static int calCount(String[] food) {
        //sets calorie count to 0
        int total = 0;

        //cycles through parameters passed on command line
        //for each item compares item with known calorie amount
        for(int i = 0; i<food.length; i++) {
          String foodItem = food[i];
          int foodItemCal = 0;
          if (foodItem.equals("burger")) {
            foodItemCal += 310;
          } else if (foodItem.equals("bigmac")) {
            foodItemCal += 560; 
          } else if (foodItem.equals("fries")) {
            foodItemCal += 250;
          } else if (foodItem.equals("mcnuggets")) {
            foodItemCal += 170;
          } else {
            foodItemCal += 0;
          }
          //adds item calories to total
          total += foodItemCal;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] foodArray = new String[args.length];
        int calories = calCount(foodArray);
        System.out.println(calories);
     }
}
```

If I type java CalorieCount burger on the command line then I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Please show the stack trace. It tells you exactly in which line the exception happens. Look at that line, find out what could be `null` there. You get an NPE when you try to call a method or access a variable through something that is `null`.

Comment: On which line do you get the null pointer exception? Could it be because you are declaring an array of a certain size, but you are never initializing its elements, i.e. `foodArray[i] == null` for every `i`.

Comment: First thing to add to your post is the error message, what line is it on? Where specifically is the null pointer? This will help you find issues/debug. I copied your code into eclipse and it compiled fine and returned "0" at the end by the way. Once I added 'burger' it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do :

```
String[] foodArray = new String[args.length];
```

You create a new array filled with null values. Then you give this array to calcount and you iterate the null values of this array. When you do :

```
foodItem.equals("burger")
```

It's equivalent to a :

```
null.equals("burger")
```

You have to fill your foodArray with your args in your main method to have it working.

And one more thing to avoid this kind of NPE : always test variables equality on the other side (I mean first the constant, then your variable) :

```
"burger".equals(foodItem)
```

So you won't get any NPE because the constant `"burger"` CAN'T be null.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] foodArray = new String[args.length];
```

This initializes the array but does not fill it with values.
So burger is not added to the array and thus not propagated to your function to be evaluated.

So:

```
foodItem == null
```

since the array is not initialized, only items are allocated.
It is always a good idea to guard against nullpointers where they could appear, in this case for foodItem.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized the array objects in `foodArray`

> String[] foodArray = new String[args.length];

It does not mean you have created `args.length` `String` objects rather you have created an array which will hold `args.length` references of `String` and initially all are assigned with `null` so you have to initialize a new `String` object and assign it to `foodArray` array as

```
for(int i = 0; i<food.length; i++) 
{
   foodArray [0]= "hello"; //new String(); Your code or your own values
}
```

before invoking `int calories = calCount(foodArray);` function

**One more side note**, it is recommended while comparing `Strings` against equality the constants should be placed on left side to prevent NPE i.e. avoid `myString.equals("hello")` and use `"hello".equals(myString)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(foodItem == null){
   continue;
}
```

Comment: you mean break; not continue

Comment: `continue` might be right if the expectation is that the array is sparse.

Comment: nope, its continue. so that it can process rest of the elements from the array!

Answer (score 0):

you are passing foodArray to method calCount() in main function which is a null

int calories = calCount(foodArray);

first initialize foodArray